# I am receiving recurssionError at /register/ (django rest framework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have create my register endpoint with DRF, so far it has been working well but since I am trying it again it is sending error.[image: recurssor error at register/]

**serializers.py**

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True,max_length=68,min_length=8,error_messages= 
     {"min_length":f"Password must be longer than {MIN_LENGTH}characters"}, required=True, validators=[validate_password])
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True,max_length=68,min_length=8,error_messages={"min_length":f"Password must be longer than {MIN_LENGTH}characters"}, required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','phone','password','password2')

    extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
            'password2': {'write_only': True}
        }
    
    def validate(self,data):
        if data["password"]!=data["password2"]:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("password does not match!")
        return data

    def create(self,validated_data):

        user = User.objects.create(
            phone=self.validated_data['phone'],
            username=self.validated_data['username'],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

**views.py**

```
class RegisterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      http_method_names = ['post']
    '''This endpoint is made to register all user with phone number and password'''
     queryset = User.objects.all()
     serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
```

Comment: Show us the view code for that url.

Comment: @JohnGordon  ```(r'register', views.RegisterViewSet)```

Comment: Is there a detailed traceback error message in the web server error log?

Comment: It seems that this line is not necessary: `http_method_names = ['post']`

Comment: What do you mean by detailed traceback error message in the web server log? That's exactly what I displayed on the screenshot and I commented the **http_method_names** but I get the same issue!